# How to dynamically change the primeNG progress background?

Tags: javascript, angular, primefaces

I'm working with the [primeNG progress component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/progressbar) and I would like to change the color of the progress bar depending on the value. So 25% 25% is blue and 75% is green.

I've found that I can override the given color with:

```
.delay .progressBarDelay .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
    background: red;
}
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="delay">
    <p>{{list.delay}}</p>                
    <div><p-progressBar class="progressBarDelay" [value]="list.value" [showValue]="false"></p-progressBar></div>
</div>
```

But now all the elements are red. And I have multiple progress bars. Is there a way to set the background color depending on the given value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change class depending on value, it think so, something like this:-

```
<p-progressBar [ngClass]="{'progressBar-green': list.value > 50, 'progresbar-red': list.value < 50}" [value]="list.value" [showValue]="false"></p-progressBar>
```

You can pass a function to ngClass where you can define your logic.

Comment: Thanks, that's work pretty well. I might try and change it so I can use a value from the component in the html so it's easier to read in the html.